# Extracting a string from gmail subject line

Tags: regex, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am new to both writing RegEx as well as Google Apps Script, and am cutting my teeth on a simple problem, extracting a specific string within an email subject line in emails with X label into a Google Sheet. I've found some info on how to get this done, but I'm not getting anything output into my sheet. The syntax of the string I'm trying to extract is (1 or 4)(A or P)(0-9)(four more alphanumeric characters). So a few examples would be 1A8D3KK, 4P3A4EE, and 1A5T4EE.

Here's what I've got:

```
function getEWO() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

  var label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName("DamageClaims");
  var threads = label.getThreads();

  for (var i=0; i<threads.length; i++)
  {
    var messages = threads[i].getMessages()[0];

    for (var j=0; j<messages.length; j++)
    {
      var date = messages.getDate();
      var sub = messages[j].getSubject();
      var getEWOstring = new RegExp ("(1|4)(A|P)[0-9]\w{4}");
      console.log(getEWOstring);
      let ewo = getEWOstring.exec(sub)
      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().appendRow([ewo])
      var debugmessage = ("EWO " + ewo + " has been added")
      SpreadsheetApp.getActive().toast(debugmessage);
    }
```

It's not outputting anything into my sheet, nor is it displaying my little debugger message.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

`/(1|4)(A|P)\d[A-Z0-9]{4}/g`

Comment: Thank you for the response. Unfortunately I change out my RegEx to that and it still doesn't throw the matching string into my Sheet. Any thoughts on that side of things?

Comment: It must have more than one problem.  Perhaps it is time to learn how to use the debugger tools.